# Google Maps APIv3 large polygon new google.maps.LatLng redundant

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am creating a map visualization. One of the things I am mapping is polygons for a large number of regions; zip codes, countys, states... Some of these entities will have a few hundred lat/long combinations to make up the polygon. Is there any alternitive to rendering them with 'new google.maps.LatLng', is there shorthand for this? It seems redundant to write that out tens of thousands of times.

I guess I could store that as a string and then have val + lat + ','+long + ']'.

The reason this is a problem is because I am storing these polygons pregenerated in a database and its taking up a lot of space

Something like this, but it doesnt work.

```
var stuff = new google.maps.LatLng;

var Poly14591; 

var Cords14591= [+ stuff +( 42.862496, -78.151154).....]
```

Answer (score 1):

If space is an issue, I would look into simplifying the boundaries. Some areas, especially bordering a body of water, have very detailed boundaries, and it may not be important to capture every detail. There is also the TopoJSON ([github](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki)) format which stores shared boundaries only once, reportedly providing an 80% reduction in size, even without simplification.

If the space saving is not worth the effort, at least look into Well-known-text (WKT, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text)). It is a standard text format for representing geometries. It's pretty concise, and an added benefit of using it is that it's well supported in mapping tools. You can probably find some code for google maps that takes WKT and automatically creates the geometries and draws them for you.

Comment: It looks like the WKT examples all have to loop through all points at runtime. Thats what I was actually attempting to avoid. The visualization I am building is going to render a large number of polygons ~2000 at most. And building/parsing them from json into google api is slower(8 seconds). But if  I store all these polygons prebuilt into a database it should be faster. I apreciate the suggestions. Maybe simplifying the polygons is the way to go.